# Match multiple occurrences in a single regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that looks like

```
$html = <<<EOT
<p><b>There are currently five entries in the London Borough of Barking &amp; Dagenham (LBBD):</b></p>
<p>My string 1<br>
My another string<br>
And this is also my string<br></p>
<p><i>Some text over here</i></p>
EOT;
```

I am trying to extract "My string 1", "My another string" and also "And this is also my string" using php preg_match
What I have so far is

```
preg_match("/There are currently .+ entries in .+:<\/b><\/p>\n<p>(.+<br>)\n+/", $html, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

But it returns me only the original string and the first occurrence. Is there a way to return an array of occurring matches in a string? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two entry points, the first is the sentence `"There are currently..."` until the opening `<p>` tag, and the second starts at the end of the last match after the `<br>` tag and the `\n` newline.

The first result will use the first entry point, the next results will use the second entry point.

`\G` is the anchor that matches the position at the end of the precedent match. This feature is interesting since the `preg_match_all` retries to match the pattern until the end of the string. But since `\G` is initialized with the start of the string at the begining, we need to avoid this case adding `(?!\A)` *(not at the start of the string)*.

Instead of using `.+`, I use `[^<]+` to avoid to get out of the tag.

To be more readable I use the verbose mode *(x modifier)* that allows to ignore spaces and to put comments  in the pattern. When I need to write literal spaces I put them between `\Q` and `\E`. All characters between `\Q` and `\E` are seen as literals *(except the pattern delimiter)* and spaces are preserved.

```
$pattern = <<<'EOD'
~                    # using this delimiter instead of / avoids to escape all
                     # the slashes

(?:
    # first entry point
    \QThere are currently \E
    [^<]+?
    \Q entries in \E
    [^<]+ </b> </p> \n <p>
  |
    # second entry point
    (?!\A)\G
    <br>\n
)
\K           # removes all that have been matched before from match result
[^<]+        # the string you want
~x
EOD;

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches))
    var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to be the most clear and detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

Use [`preg_match_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php). PHP doesn't incorporate the `g` modifier for global matches (or replaces) like most languages. Instead you need to use `preg_match()` vs. `preg_match_all()`, or specify a `$limit` when using [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) (to make it not global).

---

By default, `preg_match_all()` will sort your array of `$matches` with the flag `PREG_PATTERN ORDER`.  In other words: `$matches[0]` will be an array of full matches, `$matches[1]` will be an array of capture group 1. This means that `count($matches) !== $number_of_matches`. If you want `$matches[0]` to be an array of the first match and its capture group, use the flag `PREG_SET_ORDER`:

```
preg_match(
    "/There are currently .+ entries in .+:<\/b><\/p>\n<p>(.+<br>)\n+/",
    $html,
    $matches,
    PREG_SET_ORDER
);
```

Answer (score 0):

"Is there a way to return an array of occurring matches in a string?"
Yes, the function is [preg_match_all()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

Now, assuming that you really only want the text, and not any of the html elements, you can use this...

```
preg_match_all("/(<p>)?(.+)<br>/", $html, $matches);
```

Then, you'll want to look in `$matches[2]` for your desired array.  That's because all of the matches get stored in `$matches[0]`, the first grouping gets stored in `$matches[1]` (that's capturing the `<p>` tag), and then your content is captured in `$matches[2]` (the second grouping). If there were more groupings, they'd follow the same pattern.

[DEMO](http://3v4l.org/uNt6h)

That being said, you should probably look into using a DOM parser for something like this, as regex is generally quite bad at parsing HTML.